# regex for finding Letter after Underscore

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I would like to write a regex using unix command that identifies all strings that **do not confirm** to the following format

```
First Leter is UpperCase    
Followed by any number of letters
Underscore
Followed by UpperCase Letter
Followed by any number of letters
Underscore
and so on .............
```

**The number of underscores is variable**

```
So valid ones are                                     Invalid ones are
Alpha_Beta_Gamma                                      alph_Beta_Gamma
Alpha_Beta_Gamma_Delta                                Alpha_beta_Gamma
Alppha_Beta                                           Alpha_beta
Aliph_Theta_Pi_Chi_Ming                               Alpha_theta_Pi_Chi_Ming
```

Comment: Is `A_B_C` valid or invalid? What about `ABC`? `Abc`? `AB_CD`? The empty string?

Comment: A_B_C is Valid ABC is invalid Abc is also invalid and AB_CD is inValid it should be Ab_Cd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` has a `-v` option which inverts the match (ie. returns non-matching lines). The `-E` option puts grep into `extended-regexp` mode (which allows for `+` and parentheses to be unescaped in the pattern).

The pattern you can use is (broken up for clarity):

```
^              # beginning of string
  [A-Z]        # a single uppercase letter
  [a-z]*       # zero or more lowercase letters
  (            # start a group
    _          # an underscore
    [A-Z]      # a single uppercase letter
    [a-z]*     # zero or more lowercase letters
  )+           # close the group and it can appear one or more times
$              # end of string
```

So assuming you have a file `test.dat` that contains your 8 strings from your question:

```
grep -E -v "^[A-Z][a-z]*(_[A-Z][a-z]*)+$" test.dat
```

Returns:

```
alph_Beta_Gamma
Alpha_beta_Gamma
Alpha_beta
Alpha_theta_Pi_Chi_Ming
```

Comment: Thanks for the wunderful Explanation

Comment: The `+` after the `[a-z]` needs to be `*` to match `A_B_C`.