# Regex to find the last underscore and all text that follows it

Tags: regex

My sample text would be something like this list

- alpha123_4rf_Joe
- 45beta_Frank
- Red5Great_Sam_Fun

and I would like to be left with (with a notepad++ regex find and replace)

- alpha123_4rf
- 45beta
- Red5Great_Sam

I am just looking for the Regex as I understand notepad++ :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex for finding Letter after Underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668330/regex-for-finding-letter-after-underscore)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or are you expecting people to write your expression for you?

Answer (score 24):

Try this one:

`_[^_]+$`

Replace with an empty string.

---

To explain it:

`_` match a single _ character

`[^_]+` match any character that is **not** a _ character, one or more times (`+`)

`$` match the end of the string

Comment: To make the regex match trailing underscores without characters afterward (e.g. `HelloWorld_` => `HelloWorld`), use `_([^_]+)?$`, which optionally matches any character that is not a _ character one or more times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
/^(.*)(_.*?)$/\1/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT4sQ3/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to do this for PromQL label_replace to use for grouping as I was, this will be helpful to you:

```
[^.*]+_(.*?)$
```

I know this post is about notepad++ - however this post kept coming up in my searches and I found that the given solutions did not work with PromQLs variant of regex. Adding this answer for future folks landing here for similar reasons.